# Converting Second Order ODE to First Order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble converting this system of second order ODEs into first order.
$$ m_1x_1''= k(D-L)\cdot\frac{x_2-x_1}{D} $$
$$ m_1y_1''= k(D-L)\cdot\frac{y_2-y_1}{D} $$
$$ m_1z_1''= k(D-L)\cdot\frac{z_2-z_1}{D} $$
$$ m_2x_2''= -k(D-L)\cdot\frac{x_2-x_1}{D} $$
$$ m_2y_2''= -k(D-L)\cdot\frac{y_2-y_1}{D} $$
$$ m_2z_2''= -k(D-L)\cdot\frac{z_2-z_1}{D} $$

Where $k$ and $L$ are constants and $D=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2}$

Would I just convert each $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ into two different functions? So I would have 12 equations total?

Comment: Usually, I just set $a=x_1'$ then the first equation becomes first order in the new variable; $a' = x_1''$. I'm not sure what you're doing, but, usually introducing the velocities as independent variables does the trick.